# Remove Azure alert rule if exists using Remove-AzScheduledQueryRule

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

How do you check if an alert rule exists by its ResourceId, and then remove it. What is the syntax for the check?

```
Get-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceId "/subscriptions.....Id"    
Remove-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceId "/subscriptions/.....Id"
```

Comment: The cmdlet syntaxes you are following seems  correct here are the reference documents for the same cmdlets [Get-AzScheduledQueryRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azscheduledqueryrule?view=azps-7.1.0) & [Remove-AzScheduledQueryRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/remove-azscheduledqueryrule?view=azps-7.1.0)

Comment: yes, but how do you add the check. "if exists"

Comment: You can use the below PowerShell script -------------------

 $rulelist = Get-AzScheduledQueryRule
 foreach($item in $rulelist){
 
 if($item.id -contains "<requiredresourceid>"){
    
    Remove-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceId $item.Id
 }
 }

Comment: Does the above PowerShell script answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in above comments, You can use below PowerShell Script which will validate whether any `ScheduledQueryRule` is present for that particular ResourceId or not.

if exists it will delete the `ScheduledQueryRule` for that ResourceId.

**Here is the PowerShell Script:**

```
Connect-AzAccount
 $rulelist = Get-AzScheduledQueryRule
 foreach($item in $rulelist){
 
 if($item.id -contains "<requiredresourceid>"){
    Remove-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceId $item.Id
 }
 }
```